# 日本語のHTMLのemdashのコードは何ですか

Tags: html

## ローマ字の`&mdash;`

> My home town — a small castle town in San'in ...

日本語の文に同じ`&mdash;`を使うと、アウトプットは

> 私が生まれ育ったふるさと—山陰の小さな城下町・・・

ちょっと短いので、いちの漢字のようになって、変です。

日本語の教科書からの写真を見ると、長さは二倍のようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

日本語のHTMLのemdashのコードは何ですか。

Comment: 私の日本語は変だったら、申し訳ありませんね。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

お探しのダッシュは一般に`(倍角|2倍)(ダッシュ|ダーシ)`と呼ばれているものです．`U+2014` em dash, `&mdash;` ないし `U+2015` horizontal bar を２つつづけて使うのが一般的なようです．

> ふるさと——山陰の (em dash)
>   ふるさと――山陰の (horizontal bar)

どちらを使うべきかは割と難しい問題のようなのですが([U+2015 HORIZONTAL BARとは何か - Mac OS Xの文字コード問題に関するメモ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/NAOI/20100128/1264669476))

- mdash (U+2014)

  - 一般に倍角ダッシュは「全角ダッシュ」を2つといわれていて，JISでいう全角ダッシュに相当するのはUnicodeでいう[U+2014らしい](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0213%E9%9D%9E%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)
- horizontal bar (U+2015)

  - メジャーな変換ソフト (少なくともmozc や ATOK)では「ダッシュ」でこちらが出ます．
  - 青空文庫での採用例 ([中原中也 詩と詩人](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000026/files/55731_57416.html))
  - [2倍ダーシとは - 日本語表現辞典 Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/2%E5%80%8D%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7)
  - [日本語文章ルール 「04：全角ダッシュ（―）」 ｜ 小説 カキコ - オリジナル小説、ライトノベルや二次創作の小説・イラスト投稿サイト](http://www.kakiko.cc/howto/japanese/rule04.html)
  - [40. 全角ダーシ（ダッシュ） ｜ Dr.シローの覚え書き｜文京組版](https://bunkyo-kumihan.com/kumihan_blog/?p=483)

調べた感じでは前者が正統，後者が一般的という感じを受けました．

なお，フォントによっては２個並べた時につながらないこともあるようです (cf. [その二倍ダーシ、くっつきますか?](http://www.fukapon.com/showcase/misc/font2xdash.html), [EPUB で2倍ダーシ「——」が繋がって表示されないときの対処法 | 電子書籍について](http://suzumi-ya.com/epub/post-1396/))

余談ですが TeX なら okamacro.sty で `\--` を使えるようで，こちらも horizontal bar に細工をして使っています．

Answer (score 9):

ここで使われているのは日本語組版 (くみはん) における「倍角ダッシュ」で、2文字分の長さがあります。(通常の日本語文字のサイズは「全角」で、「倍角」は全角2文字分です。)

倍角ダッシュは、Unicodeでは定義されていないものなので、「——」と連続した全角ダッシュ (`&mdash;`) 2文字で表現することが多いです。